# Invalid cross-thread access in TimerEvent for ViewModel update

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a ViewModel (ObservableCollection) with a Load()-Method. In my UI I have a "Reload"-Button that calls the Load()-Method. Till here everything is fine.

The ViewModel is declared in App.xaml.cs so it´s globally accessible.

Now I want to update the ViewModel independent of user interaction. I created a Timer as follows:

```
public static class WhagooBackgroundManager
{
    private static bool _isInitialized = false;
    private static bool _isRunning = false;
    private static Timer _AppTimer;
    private static int _runcounter = 0;
    private static DateTime _lastRun = DateTime.MinValue;

    public static void Initialize(int pIntervall)
    {
        if (_isInitialized == false)
        {
            _isInitialized = true;
            // Init the timer - it will call OnTimerTick every "pIntervall" secods, passing null as argument to the method.
            _AppTimer = new Timer(OnTimerTick, null, pIntervall * 1000, pIntervall * 1000);
        }
    }

    private static void OnTimerTick(object state)
    {
        _runcounter = _runcounter + 1;
        // Exit if still running:
        if (_isRunning == true)
        {
            _currentstatus = "Skipped Execution, still running";
            return;
        }
        // Executing Main-Routine:
        GetLocation();
        _lastRun = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    private static async void GetLocation()
    {
        _isRunning = true;
        // Viewmodels updaten:
        await App.ViewSuggestionsData.LoadData();
        }
        _isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

When Timer runs, I get an Error: `Invalid cross-thread Access`. Searching for possible Solutions I found out, that I have to `invoke`. How do I do this exactly. And if I do this, how can I avoid that a user is pressing the "Update"-Button while Timer is running?

UPDATE:

This don´t work:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { 
    await App.ViewSuggestionsData.LoadData();
});
```

I can´t use `await` there, but I must because of calling Web Api inside.

Comment: I recommend having a look at [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) and using it instead, as it will "tick" on the UI thread so you won't have to call `Invoke` at all.

Comment: Because I have a lot of pages, I want that the app is handling this "Background activity" not on the UI thread. BackgroundWorker is not a solution because I want to run every 3 minutes.

Comment: What does the LoadData method do? I guess it's using some UI element or modifying something that a UI element is bound to. That part must happen in the UI, all else can be in the background thread.

Comment: It updates by accessing a web api my "global" ObservableCollection that is bound in MVVM to a LongListSelector. OK, I understand this with UI modifications from another thread. But which is the way to update my Collection in "Background" and let the VM Display when changes are made?

Comment: Check out Shawn Kendrot's answer. That's a good way to handle it. Also, I'd recommend you read about the async pattern in .NET. Basically, the methods that are truly async do most of their work on another thread, so calling them with await from the UI thread does not block it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to solve this. Based on the comments the simplest way would be updating the ObservableCollection on the UI thread using the Dispatcher.

```
async Task LoadData()
{
    // do some stuff
    var data = await SomeWebCall();
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => {
        MyObservableCollection = data; // or new ObservableCollection(data);
    });
}
```